# Wso2 APIM analytics server shards configuration

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I am trying to deploy two node analytics servers which are pointing to one database. And configured local shard configuration file for 1st node to index 0th,1st and 2nd shards, and 2nd node to index 3rd, 4th and 5th shards. I configured indexReplicationFactor to 1. My question is, whether above configuration will keep indexing data consistently?. Another concern is, Does having indexReplication factor as 1 will help in performance according to my deployment plan? 
[image]